# Cracking the coding interview. 4.1 Min Depth formula

Tags: c++

In CTCI, there they give a formula for the minimum depth for a binary tree and I am confused by it. Here is the code:

```
    public static int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
           return 0;
        }
        return 1 + Math.min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right));
    }
```

The definition of minimum depth is the leaf node that is shortest path from the root correct? If the definition is wrong please correct me.

DILEMMA: I made a BST with the root as 15. Then proceeded to add 5, 7, 10, 20, 25, 30, 35 to the tree. Then using the code it would output the the min is 2. 
If I were to just have added 10 and 25, the output for min would also just be 2. Is this suppose to be correct?

I translated my code into C++ here so please tell me if I made a mistake in my code to mess this up

```
     int findMin(Node* root)
     {
         if (root == NULL)
            return 0;

         return 1 + std::min(findMin(root->left), findMin(root->right));
     }

    void addNum(Node*& root, int n)
    {
        if (root == NULL){
            Node* temp = new Node(n);
            root = temp;
            return;
        }

         if (n > root->num){
             addNum(root->right, n);
         }
         else{
             addNum(root->left, n);
         }
     }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please also share the code that adds to the BST. `findMin` looks fine.

Comment: @bialpio okay i added it in. Is it my output that is wrong?

Comment: Everything looks fine, what exactly is the problem that you are having with the code?

Comment: My question is whether the depth is suppose to be 2 for both instances of the examples I gave. A tree with {10, 15, 20} has a min depth of 2 and a tree with {5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35} also has a min depth of 2 (both have root of 15). Are both the depth really suppose to be 2? because if feel like for the second tree the min depth would be 4 instead. 
I'm  sorry if I am unclear

Comment: Yes, the depth is supposed to be 2. Think of minDepth as the lowest number of nodes you need to visit in order to find a null child. In case of an empty tree, the answer is 0 - you don't need to visit any node to get null. In case of 1-node tree, the answer is 1 - you need to visit the root, but you don't need to look further. Think of min depth of a tree as a number of full levels in the tree. In your sample (both scenarios), only first two levels are full, hence the answer is 2. At least that's how the code you posted can be interpreted.

Comment: Thank you. I see the how the codes suppose to be interpretation. This is the book's code so I guess my interpretation and the books are different.

Comment: All depends on the definition of a leaf. Wikipedia: "Leaves are commonly represented by a special leaf or nil symbol, a NULL pointer, etc.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the input {15, 10, 20}

Input 1: Initially, Add `15` to the BST

```
    15
```

Input 2: Now, Add `10` to the BST

```
    15
   /
  10
```

Input 3: Now, Add `20` to the BST

```
    15
   /  \
  10  20
```

**Therefore**, The `min` and `max` height of the **BST** would be `2`

> Now, Consider another input case {15, 5, 7, 10, 20, 25, 30, 35}

Input 1: Initially, Add `15` to the BST

```
    15
```

Input 2: Now, Add `5` to the BST

```
    15
   /
  5
```

Input 3: Now, Add `7` to the BST

```
    15
   /
  5
   \
    7
```

Input 4: Now, Add `10` to the BST

```
    15
   /
  5
   \
    7
     \
      10
```

Input 5: Now, Add `20` to the BST

```
    15
   /  \
  5   20 
   \
    7
     \
      10
```

Input 6: Now, Add `25` to the BST

```
    15
   /  \
  5   20 
   \    \
    7   25
     \
      10
```

Input 7: Now, Add `30` to the BST

```
    15
   /  \
  5   20 
   \    \
    7   25
     \    \
      10   30
```

Input 8: Now, Add `35` to the BST

```
    15
   /  \
  5   20 
   \    \
    7   25
     \    \
      10   30
            \
            35
```

As you could see from the *above diagram* the `min` *height* of **BST** = `4` & `max` height = `5`

Therefore, if look properly into your `findMin` code, then you will find a bug:

```
int findMin(Node* root)
 {
     if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

     return 1 + std::min(findMin(root->left), findMin(root->right));
 }
```

**Bug** : When your `root` is pointing to the `5` (i.e left child of `15` in second example) it will return `1` to its parent. ( Why ?)

**Correction** : The below code snippet will work properly :

```
int min_depth(struct Node* root, int depth)
{
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        return depth;

    int x = (root->left != NULL) ? min_depth(root->left, depth+1) :  depth;
    int y = (root->right != NULL) ? min_depth(root->right, depth+1) : depth;

    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This cleared up a lot for me. I was confused because this was the code given in the book and gave me weird results when inputting numbers like that. Your code makes a lot of sense